# Ruby library for Flickr API?

Tags: ruby, api, flickr

Is there a solid, **production ready** library in Ruby that interacts with the Flickr API?

I [found](http://rubyforge.org/projects/flickr/) [a few](http://rubyforge.org/projects/rflickr/) by googing, but their states don't impress me much. I'm looking for something along the lines of [flickrapi for Python](http://stuvel.eu/projects/flickrapi), with nice documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've been using [flickraw](http://github.com/hanklords/flickraw) and I'm very pleased with it.  It's very straightforward to use and is quite fast.  Not sure exactly how you would define production-ready, but it's been around for a while, is more updated than other Ruby Flickr libraries, and it works.  As of this writing, it's actively maintained, with the last update being a few days ago.

Comment: this is much better than the ones I've worked with, resembles Python's  FlickrAPI